# I want to add a 10 px border to the top of my column using bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add a border to the top of my column. I am trying to use bootstrap 4, and I just can't figure it out.
I am using `<div>` tags to make the columns here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg2, col-md-2, col-sm-2, col-xs-2" style="background: #efefd8; min-height:77px;">
   <h4><b><center>
COL 1
            </center></b></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg2, col-md-2, col-sm-2, col-xs-2" style="background: #efefd8; min-height:77px;">
   <h4><b><center>
COL 2
            </center></b></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2, col-md-2, col-sm-2, col-xs-2" style="background:#efefd8; min-height:77px;">
   <h4><b><center>
COL 3
            </center></b></h4>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-lg-2, col-md-2, col-sm-2, col-xs-2" style="background: #efefd8; min-height:77px;">
  <h4><b><center>
COL 4
        </center></b></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2, col-md-2, col-sm-2, col-xs-2">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: don't use `<center>` it doesn't exist in HTML5. Also, you don't use commas in classes, `class="col-lg2, col-md-2, col-sm-2, col-xs-2"`. Just spaces.

Comment: There is no border stated in your code. Have you applied one and, if so, what happened?

Comment: I tried to add a border using CSS and it didn't work, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the commas from your column classes:

```
<div class="col-lg2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="background: #efefd8; min-height:77px;">
```

Use the class "text-center" to align text to the center.

You can add a border top by adding a custom class to the columns like "border-top"

and then in your css file:

```
.border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Other things to note, you should make an external stylesheet rather than inlining your styles in a style tag, that will become super unmanageable as you build out an entire website, the whole point of css is to have selectors that match multiple elements on your site and apply the same consistent styles across the whole site. I would strongly recommend taking a free course on CSS, which can be found all over the internet or taking a paid class.

Comment: No problem @CourtneyGeers, you should also remove most of those column classes, if you only need one column size across all devices you simply use "col-2" in Bootstrap 4, or you can do something like "col-sm-12 col-md-3" which will make your column span the whole row on small devices and below and 3 columns on devices medium an up.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting to know, since all the tutorials I looked up used both the commas and all the col classes. I will remove them though since now I know it works that way.

Comment: The only time you use commas in css like that is if you are in an actual css file, and you want to apply the same rules to multiple selectors. (i.e. ".p10, .padding10 { padding: 10px; } that would apply 10px of padding to any element with the class p10 or padding10, although in reality you would probably just use a single class.